# How to specify the wget file location (output location)

Tags: windows, wget

i have this batch file that reads an input file to grab images from a URL.  How can I specify a different output location for the wget files.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%l in (Input.txt) do (
    set line=%%l
    wget -O !line:~0,10!.jpg !line:~10!
)
```

I want the output to be in a different location.

*edit*  If wget is run from C:\wget\bin.  How can the output be saved to C:\folder\folder\x

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a download directory with the paramter `-P`.